# How to remove %20 from variable values from cookie

Tags: javascript

Here is a piece of code that I'm using to set browser cookie the issue that I have is I cant remove the "%20" and replace with a space. Whenever I have spaces in my variable value they are substituted with %20 and I'm not sure why and how to correct this problem. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

```
  var today = new Date();  
  var expiry = new Date(today.getTime() + 30 * 24 * 3600 * 1000); // plus 30 days

  function setCookie(name, value){
    document.cookie=name + "=" + escape(value) + "; path=/; expires=" + expiry.toGMTString();
  }

function putCookie(form){
   setCookie("FirstName", form[0].FirstName.value) = FirstName.replace(/%20/g," ");  
   setCookie("LastName", form[0].LastName.value) = LastName.replace(/%20/g," ");

   return true;
  }
```

Comment: Did u tried with decodeURI(str)

Answer (score 5):

Take a look at [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent).

```
decodeURIComponent('some%20val') // => 'some val'
```

Comment: Tried this and still no luck: setCookie("FirstName", form[0].FirstName.value) = decodeURIComponent('FirstName');

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: `setCookie("FirstName", decodeURIComponent (form[0].FirstName.value))`

Comment: Nope the %20 is still there, cannot figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

```
setCookie("FirstName", decodeURIComponent(form[0].FirstName.value));
setCookie("LastName", decodeURIComponent(form[0].LastName.value));
```

Checkout working demo https://jsfiddle.net/pvmzqrye/